# Could it be "control" in meaning of "to know well something"?

Tags: word-meaning

Someone who's not a native English speaker told my friend "In order to know physics well you must **control** math well.". As I understand from the context "control" could means "to know well". Is it correct or mistake? I didn't find it in the dictionaries. Maybe it's a slang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... never heard that usage of “control” before; the sentence doesn’t make sense to me. Maybe what they had in mind was the expression “to have a good grasp of”, as in, “In order to know physics well you must **have a good grasp of** math.” “Control” might be ok as a noun that replaces “grasp”- “have good control of the subject”- maybe could work. But used as a verb it sounds wrong. “Controlling” math makes it sound like you are restraining math from doing something bad, or otherwise exerting power over math- which makes no sense.